# libjpeg.so.8: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker

Запускаю PIL в Docker.

При попытке запустить докер контейнер выскакивает ошибка

> Error loading shared library libjpeg.so.8: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Сейчас образ базируется на `python:3.8.3-alpine`, установка зависимостей просходит через

```
RUN apk add gcc python3-dev musl-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev
```

также пробовал через

```
RUN apk add zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
```

Оба дают эту ошибку.

---

p.s
Проблема была в неправильной конфигурации докер файла.

Comment: `jpeg-dev` это скорее всего просто заголовки, а не сама либа, нужно ставить пакет `jpeg`